# Topic remapping using <remap> not working

Tags: ros, remapping, ros-kinetic, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Kinetic - Ubuntu 16.04

**Goal**

An app I can't control outputs data on the `/point_cloud` topic.

A Laser_scan_matcher node can accept pointcloud data on the `/cloud` topic, and can output `/PoseStamped` topic.

**What I'm doing**

I made a launch file which contains:

```
<launch>

   <remap from="tango/point_cloud" to="cloud"/>

   <node pkg="laser_scan_matcher" type="laser_scan_matcher_node" 
   name="laser_scan_matcher_node">
    <param name="use_cloud_input" value="true"/>
    <param name="publish_pose_stamped" value="true"/>
    <param name="use_imu" value="false"/>
    <param name="use_vel" value="false"/>
    <param name="use_odom" value="false"/>
   </node>
</launch>
```

(This is for live output - not bagfiles.)

Normally, rqt_graph looks something like:

(app) --> [/cloud] --> (laser_scan_matcher_node) --> [/PoseStamped]

**What I'm getting**

Instead it looks like this:

[image: image description]

What am I missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288746/topic-remapping-using-%3Cremap%3E-not-working/) by [anonymous32749](https://answers.ros.org/users/32749/anonymous32749/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2018-04-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-04-16**:
I'm not sure about it but maybe you should write  `<remap from="cloud" to="tango/point_cloud"/>` if you do the remapping in this launch file or write `<remap from="tango/point_cloud" to="cloud"/>` in the launch file that launch your app.

**Comment by [anonymous32749](https://answers.ros.org/users/32749/anonymous32749/) on 2018-04-16**:
@Delb remapping from "cloud" to "tango/point_cloud" worked, funnily enough! Instead of the node using the /cloud input, it started using /point_cloud as input. Thanks!

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-04-16**:
When you do `<remap from="x" to="y"/>` you ask a node to change its input/output topic `x` to a topic `y` so when you had your issue you were asking the node to change an unknown input topic which is why it didn't worked. (So I think my other solution would have worked too)

**Comment by [anonymous32749](https://answers.ros.org/users/32749/anonymous32749/) on 2018-04-16**:
@Delb But as I said, I can't control the source node. I can't specify that it has to output to /cloud.  I can only edit the launch file of the Laser Scan Matcher node.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-04-16**:
Oh yes I ommited that sorry. (You should now mark your question as closed since the problem is solved)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-16**:\

> You should now mark your question as closed since the problem is solved

Please don't do that.

@OperationCrossbow: please post what you ended up using that solved your question as an answer. Then accept your own answer.

We tend to not close questions here on ROS Answers. We mark them answered.

**Comment by [anonymous32749](https://answers.ros.org/users/32749/anonymous32749/) on 2018-04-18**:
@gvdhoorn It says "You should now mark your question as closed since the problem is solved" above your comment. I'm getting conflicting information here. Also, ROS Answers tells me I have insufficient points to accept my own answer.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-18**:
@OperationCrossbow: @Delb may not be aware of this 'policy'. I did not make this up myself, I'm just passing along what I've observed over the past 5 years (yes, that is a logical fallacy) and has worked well.

An answered question is clearly visible as such: it gets a checkmark. A closed ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-18**:
.. question only shows `[ closed ]` in the question list, but it's unclear as to why it was closed.

Finally: answered is some form of closure, but closing does not always mean answering.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-04-18**:
Yes I'm sorry I thought it was the right thing to do, my apologies.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-18**:
No problem.

**Comment by [anonymous32749](https://answers.ros.org/users/32749/anonymous32749/) on 2018-04-18**:
@gvdhoorn I also lack sufficient 'points' to reopen other past questions I've closed. Will keep questions open in future, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ended up using `<remap from="cloud" to="tango/point_cloud"/>` instead.

Instead of `/point_cloud` changing into `/cloud` and the node accepting this as input, it changed the node to accept  `/point_cloud` directly. It serves me in my goal, so this work-around is good enough.

---

Originally posted by [anonymous32749](https://answers.ros.org/users/32749/anonymous32749/) with karma: 62 on 2018-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0